# Got lost in CSS dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

i was able to make the dropdown menu already but when i tried to view it on other pc the secondlevel ul was misplaced and not below on it's li. So i tried to recode but i got lost. Please help.

Here is my html markup:

```
<div id="main-nav" class="menufont">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">ONE</a></li>
        <li class="sec">TWO
            <ul id="twosecond" class="leveltwo">
                <li>TWO A</li>
                <li>TWO B</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sec1">THREE
            <ul id="threesecond" class="leveltwo">
                <li>THREE A</li>
                <li>THREE B</li>
                <li>THREE C</li>
                <li>THREE D</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>FOUR</li>
        <li>FIVE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my messed up css:

```
ul.leveltwo {
    background: #c7000d;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 7px;
    font: 16px Helvetica, Arial;
}

ul.leveltwo li {
    color: #fff;
}

#twosecond li, #threesecond li {
    font: 16px Arial;
    display:block;
    padding: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
}

#twosecond, #threesecond {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav li.sec:hover ul, #nav li.sec1:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The ul with class .leveltwo shows when i hover on it's main li but the ul of "TWO" is not aligned with it. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: "when i tried to view it on other pc" isn't a good suggestion. Which browser is causing the problem? And what version?

Comment: browser is same Firefox 7 but the other one where it was messed up is running fbsd.

Comment: mmm what about "#menusecond, #aboutsecond" and "#menusecond li, #aboutsecond li"? I can't find them in you html structure.
Are you sure the name are correct?

Comment: @ Marco Pace: Oh sorry, in my actual html markup it is #menusecond and #aboutsecond too. I edited the css above already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:none` to your `.leveltwo` class and take out the  `#twosecond #threesecond` tags.  The `position:absolute is making the sub menus look like they're showing up under THREE.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r4gAQ/3/

Though I will say, I'd look into a jQuery solution, maybe a premade one like MLDDM. They have nice solutions that allow for vertical and horizontal menus.  Also, hovering using pure CSS breaks in IE6... not that anyone should use that anymore.

Comment: Thanks but my problem actually is the secondlevel menu of item "TWO" is showing up under "THREE". Thanks again.

Comment: I'm just saying it shows #twosecond under #sec and #threesecond under #sec1 in the example I've reproduced.

Comment: Thanks again. But how do i make the secondlevel of "TWO" align under it when i hover on it? Because it messes up on other resolution when i try to put (top: left: bottom: right:) properties.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by aligning under it.  Do you want it to be moved to the right, like indented?

Comment: When i hover on TWO, the secondlevel of TWO shows under THREE. When i hover on THREE, the secondlevel of THREE shows under THREE. Sorry about my explanations, I'm not good at conversing in English.

Comment: It's because you're absolutely positioning things. Take out "position:absolute" on the #twosecond, #threesecond tag.

Comment: Oh there! i added position:relative on #nav li and position:absolute on ul.leveltwo. Thanks a lot! Now i can sleep. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Rechecked my post.  This might be the CSS that would help you out. Try it out!

```
#nav li{
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav li ul.leveltwo li{
    border:none;
}

#nav li ul{
    background: #c7000d;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 7px;
    font: 16px Helvetica, Arial;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:0;
    display:none;
}

#nav .sec:hover ul, #nav .sec1:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```